# Removing NSInteger warning using __LINE__

Tags: objective-c, c-preprocessor, iphone-64bit

I have a log function:

```
#define LOGERROR(err) if(err) {                     \
    LOGTRACE(@"[NSError] %s (%d): (%d:%@) Reason: %@",  \
        __PRETTY_FUNCTION__,                            \
        __LINE__,                                       \
        err.code,                                       \
        err.domain,                                     \
        err.localizedDescription)                       \
}
```

When I call it with

```
LOGERROR(playerItem.error);
```

I get a warning: "NSInteger should not be used as a format argument, add an explicit cast to long".

Xcode's autofix inserts %ld before LOGERROR, which is wrong.

I think this warning comes from the use of `__LINE__`, which according to https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Standard-Predefined-Macros.html returns an int.

How can I remove the warning from this call?

Comment: I think it's actually annoyed about `err.code`, which returns an `NSInteger`. Cast it: `(long)(err.code)`, and then use `%ld` in the format string.

Comment: ah, thanks that was it. Just misread it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to formalize the answer I gave in a comment:

The compiler is complaining about the use of `err.code`, which returns an NSInteger. Cast it to a `long`: `(long)(err.code)`, and then use `%ld` in the format string.